# wordpress "the_custom_logo" not fetching my image in the library

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create my owm custom theme in wordpress, i want to pull the selected logo which is already in my library, i have trouble getting the "the_custom_logo" method to work.

Upon checking this method turns out that, when it calls the "get_theme_mod('custom_logo')", it doesnt return any id. Below is my code.

//functions.php

```
 function custom_wordpress_theme_themesupport(){
    //Adds dynamic title tag support
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
    add_theme_support('custom-logo',array(
        'height'      => 100,
        'width'       => 400,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'flex-width'  => true,
        'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
       'unlink-homepage-logo' => true,
    ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','custom_wordpress_theme_themesupport');
```

//header.php

```
<header class="header text-center">     
    <a class="site-title pt-lg-4 mb-0" href="index.html">SiteName.dev</a>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" >
       
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" >
            <?php 
                if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
                    the_custom_logo();
                }
            ?>
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
It might sound silly, but are you selecting your image from the "Site Identity" section?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made this mistake where I uploaded the logo under the 'site icon' and not the 'logo' section under Appearance > Customize > Site Identity.

The code should work fine once you uploaded your logo there.